# How to match image based on border of image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, pyautogui

This is more of a 'what is this called' kind of question than a technical one. I have recently started playing with PyAutoGUI and I am using it to do some automation. In order to improve the speed of the overall function I am trying to narrow down the 'region' in which its looking. How would I identify a region by looking for a specific "border" ignoring the internal contents. I don't really need any code, unless your just that bored, just trying to learn what techniques are available to accomplish this task or maybe some helpful keywords that I can use in my search. I am having a very difficult time finding any resources that relate to my objective.

For example, how would I match the entire dimensions of the following picture regardless of what is inside the frame.

[image]

Comment: If you know every possible specific "border", you could subtract each of them from the test image and see which results in an outer border area that's empty (or nearly so). Doesn't sound like a time-saver.

Comment: It has a static border that never changes, its only whats inside the border that changes. I thought about maybe trying to capture each sides border then calculating the internal dimensions, that just seems like a bad way to do it. I presume there is some sort of technique used for this exact problem.

Comment: I don't believe there is — sometimes you have to create the software that needed yourself.

Comment: if the border is always the exact same size, you can try `cv2.matchTemplate`. idk how well it will work with different inside contents, if not you can try template matching each border but that will be abit trickier

Comment: @Ta946 I *think* this is what I was looking for. Just started reading a few articles about it and will post my solution if/when I figure it out. TY!

Comment: If I was you, I'd use opencv, and try different image detection techniques, in your case, I think HSV Filtering would work just fine. If you can't figure it out by yourself, I have some experience using HSV Filtering, and I could write the code out for you.